# Constant TAO CORBA IOR

Tags: corba, object-to-string, tao

How to configure TAO corba server so that IOR string of this server generated from object_to_string is constant?

Each time the IOR string generated from object_to_string changes once server restarts. This is inconvenient since client has to update its cached server IOR string via reloading IOR file or namingservice accessing. As a result, it would be useful if server can generate a constant IOR string, no matter how many times it restarts.

My corba server is based on ACE+TAO and i do remember TAO supports constant IOR string: the IOR string each time it generates are same, and the solution is add some configurations for server. But i could not remember these configurations now.

=============================================
**UPDATE:**

In ACE_wrappers/TAO/tests/POA/Persistent_ID/server.cpp, i added a new function named testUniqe() which is similiar to creatPOA method. And the update file content is:

```
void testUniqu(CORBA::ORB_ptr orb_, PortableServer::POA_ptr poa_){

  CORBA::PolicyList policies (2);
  policies.length (2);          
                                                     //IOR is the same even it is SYSTEM_ID
  policies[0] =   poa_->create_id_assignment_policy (PortableServer::USER_ID); 

  policies[1] =   poa_->create_lifespan_policy (PortableServer::PERSISTENT);
  PortableServer::POAManager_var poa_manager = poa_->the_POAManager ();
  PortableServer::POA_ptr child_poa_ =   poa_->create_POA ("childPOA", poa_manager.in (), policies);

  // Destroy the policies
  for (CORBA::ULong i = 0;  i < policies.length ();  ++i)  {
      policies[i]->destroy ();
    }

  test_i *servant =   new test_i (orb_, child_poa_);

  PortableServer::ObjectId_var oid = PortableServer::string_to_ObjectId("xushijie");
  child_poa_->activate_object_with_id (oid,  servant);

  PortableServer::ObjectId_var id =  poa_->activate_object (servant);
  CORBA::Object_var object = poa_->id_to_reference (id.in ());

  test_var test =  test::_narrow (object.in ());
  CORBA::String_var ior = orb_->object_to_string(test.in());
  std::cout<<ior.in()<<std::endl;

  poa_->the_POAManager()->activate();
  orb_->run();
}

int
ACE_TMAIN (int argc, ACE_TCHAR *argv[])
{

  try
    {
      CORBA::ORB_var orb =
        CORBA::ORB_init (argc, argv);

      int result = parse_args (argc, argv);
      CORBA::Object_var obj =
        orb->resolve_initial_references ("RootPOA");

      PortableServer::POA_var root_poa =
        PortableServer::POA::_narrow (obj.in ());

      PortableServer::POAManager_var poa_manager =
        root_poa->the_POAManager ();
      testUniqu(orb.in(), root_poa.in());
       orb->destroy ();
    }
  catch (const CORBA::Exception& ex)
    {
      ex._tao_print_exception ("Exception caught");
      return -1;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the output server IORs are still different once restart. I also compared this code to the one in Page 412(Advance Corba Programming), but still fail..

///////////////////////////////////

UPDATE:

With "server  -ORBListenEndpoints iiop://:1234 > /tmp/ior1", the generated two IORs are:

IOR:010000000d00000049444c3a746573743a312e300000000001000000000000007400000001010200150000007368696a69652d5468696e6b5061642d543431300000d2041b00000014010f0052535453f60054c6f80c000000000001000000010000000002000000000000000800000001000000004f41540100000018000000010000000100010001000000010001050901010000000000
IOR:010000000d00000049444c3a746573743a312e300000000001000000000000007400000001010200150000007368696a69652d5468696e6b5061642d543431300000d2041b00000014010f0052535468f60054da280a000000000001000000010000000002000000000000000800000001000000004f41540100000018000000010000000100010001000000010001050901010000000000

The result for tao_catior for ior1 and ior2:

```
ior1: 
The Byte Order: Little Endian
The Type Id:    "IDL:test:1.0"
Number of Profiles in IOR:      1
Profile number: 1
IIOP Version:   1.2
    Host Name:  **
    Port Number:        1234
    Object Key len:     27
    Object Key as hex:
    14 01 0f 00 52 53 54 53 f6 00 54 c6 f8 0c 00 00
    00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
    The Object Key as string:
    ....RSTS..T................
    The component <1> ID is 00 (TAG_ORB_TYPE)
            ORB Type: 0x54414f00 (TAO)
    The component <2> ID is 11 (TAG_CODE_SETS)
        Component length: 24
        Component byte order:   Little Endian
        Native CodeSet for char:  Hex - 10001   Description - ISO8859_1
        Number of CCS for char 1
        Conversion Codesets for char are:
        1)  Hex - 5010001       Description - UTF-8
        Native CodeSet for wchar:  Hex - 10109  Description - UTF-16
        Number of CCS for wchar 0
ecoding an IOR:


//ior2
The Byte Order: Little Endian
The Type Id:    "IDL:test:1.0"
Number of Profiles in IOR:      1
Profile number: 1
IIOP Version:   1.2
    Host Name:  **
    Port Number:        1234
    Object Key len:     27
    Object Key as hex:
    14 01 0f 00 52 53 54 68 f6 00 54 da 28 0a 00 00
    00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
    The Object Key as string:
    ....RSTh..T.(..............
    The component <1> ID is 00 (TAG_ORB_TYPE)
            ORB Type: 0x54414f00 (TAO)
    The component <2> ID is 11 (TAG_CODE_SETS)
        Component length: 24
        Component byte order:   Little Endian
        Native CodeSet for char:  Hex - 10001   Description - ISO8859_1
        Number of CCS for char 1
        Conversion Codesets for char are:
        1)  Hex - 5010001       Description - UTF-8
        Native CodeSet for wchar:  Hex - 10109  Description - UTF-16
        Number of CCS for wchar 0
```

The diff result is:

```
<     14 01 0f 00 52 53 54 53 f6 00 54 c6 f8 0c 00 00 
---
>     14 01 0f 00 52 53 54 68 f6 00 54 da 28 0a 00 00 
19c19
<     ....RSTS..T................
---
>     ....RSTh..T.(..............
```

Similar diff result is:

```
<     14 01 0f 00 52 53 54 62 fd 00 54 2c 9a 0e 00 00 
---
>     14 01 0f 00 52 53 54 02 fd 00 54 f9 a9 09 00 00 
19c19
<     ....RSTb..T,...............
---
>     ....RST...T................
```

The difference is in ObjectKey.

============================================

update:

Instead of using above code, i find a better solution with helper TAO_ORB_Manager which is used NamingService and TAO/examples/Simple. TAO_ORB_Manager encapsulates API and generate persistent IORs, as example code in Simple.cpp:

```
  if (this->orb_manager_.init_child_poa (argc, argv, "child_poa") == -1){
      CORBA::String_var str  = 
        this->orb_manager_.activate_under_child_poa (servant_name,
                                                     this->servant_.in ());
  }
```

This is some description for TAO_ORB_Manager:

```
class TAO_UTILS_Export TAO_ORB_Manager
{
  /**
   * Creates a child poa under the root poa with PERSISTENT and
   * USER_ID policies.  Call this if you want a @a child_poa with the
   * above policies, otherwise call init.
   *
   * @retval -1 Failure
   * @retval 0 Success
   */
  int init_child_poa (int &argc,
                      ACE_TCHAR *argv[],
                      const char *poa_name,
                      const char *orb_name = 0);


  /**
   * Precondition: init_child_poa has been called.  Activate <servant>
   * using the POA <activate_object_with_id> created from the string
   * <object_name>. Users should call this to activate objects under
   * the child_poa.
   *
   * @param object_name  String name which will be used to create
   *                     an Object ID for the servant.
   * @param servant  The servant to activate under the child POA.
   *
   * @return 0 on failure, a string representation of the object ID if
   *           successful.  Caller of this method is responsible for
   *           memory deallocation of the string.
   */
  char *activate_under_child_poa (const char *object_name,
                                  PortableServer::Servant servant);
  ...................
}
```

After build, I can get what i want with -ORBListenEndpoints iiop://localhost:2809 option. Thanks @Johnny Willemsen help

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the POA with a persistent lifespan policy, see ACE_wrappers/TAO/tests/POA/Persistent_ID as part of the TAO distribution.

Comment: Thanks @Johnny Willemsen. This example is the same as described in README. I added new function checkuniq in server.cpp to check whether IOR are the same when server is restart. But the result is the as what i expected.

Comment: You have to start the server on a fixed port, see the -ORBEndpoint commandline option

Comment: The results still do not match. I tried twice for each  "-ORBListenEndpoints iiop://:1234" and "-ORBListenEndpoints iiop://localhost:1234", and "-ORBEndpoint iiop://:1234".

Comment: Please run TAO/utils/catior/tao_catior on the IOR and see that is in

Comment: Update as above. The object_key is used to identify unique object in the server and objectid of objectKey can locate servant attached to the POA. Does this mean that child_poa_ created in two different startup are not the same though both have same POA name?

Comment: If you use the correct policies the object reference will stay the same, but not sure why it doesn't work in your setup. At this moment I am not able to dive into this due to lack of time. Please use the TAO mailing list, see http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/ACE-mail.html

Comment: What happens when you use an explicit IP address to listen on?

Comment: With explicit IP address, the IOR is still not persistent.

Comment: What happens if you use the IOR written on first invocation on the restart?

Comment: Using previoius ior string, the invocation at client will throw ""(8394|139721312069440) EXCEPTION, myexception
system exception, ID 'IDL:omg.org/CORBA/OBJECT_NOT_EXIST:1.0'
OMG minor code (2), described as 'Failed to create or locate Object Adapter.', completed = NO